# Sites list getting empty results in graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-files

We are getting empty results even though we are having sites in the sharepoint account.

API - https://graph.microsoft.com/sites

[MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-1.0#list-all-site-collections)

Method - GET

We have **Sites.Read.All** and **Sites.ReadWrite** permission in graph access token.

Could you please help us to solve this issue.

Comment: you have `Sites.Read.All and Sites.ReadWrite` within the `roles` claim in the access token?

Answer (score 0):

According [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-1.0#list-all-site-collections) and [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/14387#issuecomment-930432150), calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites` is supported with only application permissions only. With delegated permissions you can filter only root site `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$filter=siteCollection/root ne null`

I would prefer using `search` to get all sites

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```